# What is the WPF equivalent of Silverlight's ScrollViewer.ScrollIntoView?

Tags: wpf

What is the WPF equivalent of Silverlight's ScrollViewer.ScrollIntoView?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `FrameworkElement` class implements a `BringIntoView()` method - if you are dealing with a class that inherits from `FrameworkElement` you should be able to call that method. The method essentially raises the `RequestBringIntoViewEvent` which will bubble up the visual tree. The `ScrollViewer` and a bunch of other classes handle the event and then call their internal logic to bring the element into view.

Also some `ItemControls` such as `DataGrid` or `ListBox` provide a `ScrollIntoView()` method to make a child visible.

The `ScrollIntoView()` in turns calls the `OnBringItemIntoView` method in the `ItemsControl` class and in turn calls the `FrameworkElement` but also deals with a `VirtualizingPanel` where you might not have a `FrameworkElement` already created.

Comment: That sounds far more pleasant than the Silverlight version.