# Is there a WPF equivalent Silverlight's ScrollIntoView?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, scroll

Is there a WPF equivalent Silverlight's `ScrollIntoView`?

I would like to do something like this:

```
scrollViewer.ScrollIntoView(this, 0, 4, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500)));
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346440/what-is-the-wpf-equivalent-of-silverlights-scrollviewer-scrollintoview

Answer (score 4):

[FrameworkElement.BringIntoView Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598110.aspx)

Comment: Yes please.  I've come across it but the implementations I've seen require `GetBoundsRelativeTo` which is not available in WPF.  I'm also wanting to animate if possible.

Answer (score 0):

till now i am using

```
scrollViewer1.ScrollToVerticalOffset(100)

scrollViewer1.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(100)
```

Methods

Comment: does this help you.? if so... vote up or mark it as answer... that will help others to try this solution